# Have app launch with last selected tab select

Tags: flutter

When my app launches I want to set the initialIndex on my DefaultTabController to the index that the user was on when the app exited.  What is the appropriate way to persist this?

1) Should I listed to a change in tabs and save that value each time?  How do I listen for a change in tabs?

2) Should I save the selected index when the app closes?  How do I detect the app is closing?

Answer (score -1):

You can persist the selected index using [shared preferences](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences) plugin. Just load the info in initstate and open the tab.

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't really my question.

Comment: Could you explain what you need? You can find tabs documentation here - https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/design/tabs and check 'initialIndex ' property in DefaultTabController class

Comment: 1) Should I listed to a change in tabs and save that value each time? How do I listen for a change in tabs?

2) Should I save the selected index when the app closes? How do I detect the app is closing?